# What is the best way to analyze additional attributes in a market basket analysis?

Tags: association-measure, association-rules

I am performing a market basket analysis of customers and the products they purchased.  I did an a priori analysis on all of the transactions on the products they purchased to determine which items are likely bought together.

I have additional attributes (industry, geography, etc.) about the customers (B2B), and I would like to find purchasing trends.  For instance, do customers in the financial services industry buy a group of products more frequently than customers in the retail industry (or all customers)?

I can think of three ways to do this, but I am not sure which one is correct:

1. Add the attributes as an additional product in the transaction (so to speak), so the a priori algorithm itself will determine if there is a relationship between the *industry* product and the *purchased* products
2. Run the a priori analysis on pre-filtered customer transactions based on an attribute (e.g., run it on only retail customer transactions)
3. Run some other statistical analysis (chi-square?) to determine if a customer group differs

Comment: Please reread and carefully edit your question.  It's unclear right now, esp. the "For instance" sentence and point #1.

Comment: Thanks @rolando2.  I've updated the question for clarity.

Comment: So you have a clients table with client name and attributes (e.g. sector) and then you have a products table with product name/code and atttributes (e.g. colour, size, type, etc.), is that correct ? Can you explain your dataset?

Comment: @Zhubarb, we have a table of clients with attributes (e.g., sector) and the products each client purchased in 2013.  We do not know if the client purchased X and then Y -- we only know that they bought X and Y in 2013.  There are 50 products.

Comment: Please clarify: are you interested only in a) likelihood of buying the various baskets or, also b) likelihood of buying at different quantity levels, or, also c) likelihood of spending different amounts on purchases of each basket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your data.

If you have customer grouped already and there is only few customer groups, then 2. would result in a set of association rules for each customer group. A result easy to understand /explain to others.

Ex.: Customer group X -> buy item Y and Z, 43% of the time

If customers are not grouped already but there is only a few attributes, then 1. makes more sense, resulting in a set of association rules, including the customer attributes. Again an easy-to-understand result.

Ex.: Attribute X -> buys item Y 86% of the time

Though if customers are not grouped, and you have many attributes, then you need to get creative. One solution would be to use some sort of clustering algorithm on the customers first, and then go back to option 2.